# Query a Database to Find a Match with MVC 3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am building an MVC-based e-commerce application with MVC3 based on nopCommerce. I am needing to restrict the sale of certain products based on zip code. For example, the sale of slingshots is illegal in New Mexico, so if you try and purchase a slingshot from our sight and your zip code is from New Mexico, you are redirected to your shopping cart and informed you cannot purchase the product.

To accomplish this, I have created a SQLCE database of zip codes and given them a bool value of Restricted. I want to take the zip code given by the customer during the checkout process and compare it to the database I have created, determining whether or not it is restricted. Then I will use if statements to handle the order based on the results.

I am new to MVC3 and .Net in general, so my experience is practically null. My research seems to indicate there are several methods for doing this(Linq To SQL, Entity Frameworks, ETC). Is this true? What is the most efficient what to accomplish this comparison?

**Edit**

After further reading I will make my question more concrete. How do I ask the db "Hey, do you have this zip?" using Linq to Entities?

Comment: You should probably start here first: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/nerddinner/introducing-the-nerddinner-tutorial, as any answers posted here will not make any sense without some familiarity with the framework.

Comment: I have actually been working with the MVC Music Store tutorial as it suggested in the link you sent, so perhaps I underestimated my experience level. Nonetheless, I am pretty green.

Comment: If I could, I would probably change the approach…instead of waiting at the end (and let the user have the surprise that he can’t purchase half of his items based on some law) why not simply link the zip code to his current account and obtain that information after he logs in. Now with that in hand, you can now display or not products based on his current zip code. This way, he’ll know right from the beginning that he can’t add this product to his shopping cart. Wouldn’t this be more proactive? Just asking!

Comment: While this would work with current account holders, this would not work for first time customers on the site. The account is created based on the information they give during their initial checkout.

Comment: The most efficient way performance-wise is probably not the most efficient way regarding development comfort and speed. What do you mean with "most efficient"? Do you expect extreme traffic on the site so that every millisecond of data access matters?

Comment: To clarify, the efficiency I am looking for is in development. We will not have immense loads of traffic. I am, however, trying to add this feature as soon as possible so the site can go live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After further reading I will make my question more concrete. How do I
>   ask the db "Hey, do you have this zip?" using Linq to Entities?

The answer to your question can be as simple as this:

```
var hasZip = db.BannedZipSet.Count(z => z.Zip == userZip) > 0;
```

Linq-to-Entities converts Linq expressions to SQL statements.

However, there is a learning curve when setting up Entity Framework for the first time, so take that into consideration.

Comment: That does seem to be the case. Do I need to work with the db as an Entity(ie restrictedzipsentities)?

Comment: Also, is there a method you suggest instead of Entity Framework?

Comment: I do like EF when I'm on the Windows platform. It looks like you might only need one table mapping for your problem, so getting started may not be that difficult.

Comment: It's actually two tables, but I have decided not to you Entity Framework for this specific task. Thanks for your input.